# Where do I specify my SSL port for IISExpress?

Tags: asp.net, ssl, asp.net-core

OK, so I used to be able to change the SSL port number in the project properties dialog, but after the asp.net 5 RC1 update, the SSL field is read-only:

[image]

It ignores the SSLPort value when I attempt to edit the .xproj directly:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <DevelopmentServerPort>17204</DevelopmentServerPort>
    <SSLPort>44303</SSLPort>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

And it also resets the port in my app host config file ($[solutionDir].vs\config\applicationhost.config) back to the original value when I change the binding and launch my project.

```
        <site name="WebApplication1" id="8">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\WebApplication1\wwwroot" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:17833:localhost" />
                <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44303:localhost" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

What gives? Where is Visual Studio getting this value from, and how do I change it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Open `launchSettings.json` under the `./Properties` folder. The **int** value in iisSettings > iisExpress > sslPort is where it's read from. You can change that value to whatever you want.

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "iisExpress": {
      "sslPort": <ssl-port-value>
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It must be in the range 44300-44399 for IISExpress to actually enable SSL. If you put something like 6000 then it won't work and you'll get a blank page. Apparently you can use any port running as an admin. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-without-administrative-privileges

Comment: @Simon_Weaver but where is `./Properties` folder and its `launchSettings.json`? Is that only available and specific to .net core?

Comment: @DonCheadle yes. For traditional it’s different. It should be easy to lookup.